# Phpunit testing, error when including file

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

Very new to php unit and can't exactly work out whats wrong. My class is as follows:

```
<?php

    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/assets/php/global_php_includes.php';
    use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

    final class PesticideTests extends TestCase {

        public function addPesticideTest() {

            $data = array(
                "code" => randomString(16),
                "created_by" => $_SESSION['userCode'],
                "company_code" => "TEST_COMPANY",
                "crop_code" => "TEST_CROP",
                "content" => "TEST_CONTENT",
                "comments" => "TEST_COMMENTS",
                "function" => "TEST_FUNCTION",
                "pcs_no" => 0123,
                "phi" => "TEST_PHI",
                "product_name" => "TEST_PRODUCT",
                "substance" => "TEST_SUBSTANCE",
                "date_of_reg_review" => "01-01-0001",
                "use_by_date" => "01-01-0001",
                "off_label_approval" => "TEST_OFF_LABEL_APPROVED",
                "latest_time_of_application" => "TEST_LATEST_TIME_OF_APPLICATION",
                "max_individual_dose" => "TEST_MAX_INDIVIDUAL_DOSE",
                "max_total_dose" => "TEST_MAX_TOTAL_DOSE",
                "max_no_applications" => "TEST_MAX_NO_APPLICATIONS",
                "method_of_application" => "TEST_METHOD_OF_APPLICATION",
                "status" => 'inactive'
              );

              $result = addPesticide($connection, $data);
              $this->assertEquals(1, $result);
        }
    }
```

the command I run to test it is `./vendor/bin/phpunit tests/PesticideTests.php`

and the error I get is

```
PHP Warning:  include(/assets/php/global_php_includes.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\tapp\tests\PesticideTests.php on line 3

Warning: include(/assets/php/global_php_includes.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\tapp\tests\PesticideTests.php on line 3
PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/assets/php/global_php_includes.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\tapp\tests\PesticideTests.php on line 3

Warning: include(): Failed opening '/assets/php/global_php_includes.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\tapp\tests\PesticideTests.php on line 3
PHPUnit 9.5.2 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

W                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 00:00.014, Memory: 4.00 MB

There was 1 warning:

1) Warning
No tests found in class "PesticideTests".

WARNINGS!
```

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong? If I also run it as just ./vendor/bin/phpunit tests then I get the error "No tests found". Pretty confused

EDIT:

I have fixed the test not being found by naming it by the wrong convention, still getting an error for the include file

Comment: Tests need to be either annotated as tests or the method name needs to begin with "test". Yours ends with "Test".

Comment: @El_Vanja I actually realised that, about the edit the question now. Still getting an error with the include line though :(

Answer (score 0):

When running your code withing phpunit there is no `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` set. This only gets set when running in the context of a webserver. Just replace this with the directory where the `assets` directory is.

Comment: Still get an error `PHP Warning:  include(../assets/php/global_php_includes.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\tapp\tests\PesticideTest.php on line 3`

Comment: Well, I would start by using the absolute path for the include file. If that works, you can either leave it like that, or try to figure out why the relative path is not resolved correctly.